# Have Firebug break when a global variable x is defined

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, scope, firebug

We have a very large JavaScript application, where after many months of coding there have inevitably sprung a couple scope slip ups where a variable is defined without using the `var` keyword in the following fashion:

```
function() {  
  x = 5; ...  
}
```

instead of:

```
function() {  
  var x = 5; ...  
}
```

This is happening somewhere - we're not sure where - and searching for the variable name in question is difficult, since it's a common word that appears 1000s of times in our source.

Is there a way to ask Firebug to break on the line that first creates a given global variable? To clarify, I would like to break at exactly the instant when `window.x` switches from `undefined` to a defined value, and to break statement.

I've tried creating a watch expression and hoped I could turn it into a breakpoint, but I can't seem to create watch expressions without some kind of context or scope.

If this isn't possible with Firebug, I'd be interested in anything that can accomplish this in Firefox in general.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Provided a few things

1. You know the name of the variable
2. You don't have a variable with that name in the global scope (declared outside functions), but only inside functions.
3. There are calls to the function that declares the variable.

this little script would do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.__defineSetter__("x", function(value) { console.trace(); });
x = 1;
</script>
```

You'll get a trace of the executed code before that assignment.

It may fail to report some situations, so take a look at [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). Load all your JS files right there and lint them.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code formatter? I can't get it to work with my example.

Comment: yeah you have to add a lot of spaces before each line to have it formatted -- had the same issue entering my question :)

Comment: Very nice approach (that works!), and thanks for making me discover the \__defineSetter\__ "magic" method.

Comment: See @Maciek answer below for what worked for him. He used `debugger;` instead of `console.trace` to do the debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I ended up using by modifying Ionut G. Stan's solution:

```
window.__defineSetter__("name", function(value) {
  if (value=="div") {
    debugger;
  }
});
```

I used `debugger` instead of `console.trace()`, so I could stop and look at it mid-execution. With `console.trace()` I got a bazillion trace statements due to this line executing many times.

The leaky scope turned out to be buried in Dojo, where Dojo is setting that variable to the name of a processed element.

Comment: I've used "debugger" initially, but I couldn't see the line where the variable was assigned, so I thought it won't help you. Anyway, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that only works in Firefox because it uses the Firefox-specific [`watch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) method.

Put this piece of Javascript at the very top of your html page, just after the `<head>` tag:

```
<script>
window.watch('x', function() { debugger });
</script>
```

Note that `watch` works on any Javascript object (`window` is the global Javascript object).

Answer (score 1):

View your web page on the SeaMonkey browser (I use version 1.1.16) and look at the error console, you will see a message of this type for each assignment to an undeclared variable :

```
Warning: assignment to undeclared variable x
Source File: http://....js
Line: ##
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to debugging, I would advise to check your code with [JSLint](http://jslint.com/), which reports unexpected assignments in the global scope as errors.

There are several command-line bundles of jslint, such as [jslint4java](https://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/) which can be used cross-platform in [Ant build scripts](http://addyosmani.com/blog/client-side-build-process/).